# Certificate signed by Intermediate shows as self-signed certificate

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, hosting

I'm currently in the process of migrating the hosting of a service of mine from a Managed hosting (running Lighspeed + Cpanel) to my own Managed hosting, running Nginx.

Everything is running fine in Nginx 1.6.0, **but my problem is that my certificate shows as self-signed**. I installed the SSL certificate including the chained certificate as per 
http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-nginx.htm

However, even trying the configuration on [NGinx SSL certificate authentication signed by intermediate CA (chain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431528/nginx-ssl-certificate-authentication-signed-by-intermediate-ca-chain) it does not work.

If I input my website on `http://sslcheck.globalsign.com/en_US` it shows as it's a self-signed certificate.

Below is my virtual host configuration regarding SSL:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  443 ssl;

    server_name    host02.website.com *.website.com;
    root           /spacedata/website.com;
    index index.php index.html /;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:AES128-SHA:RC4-SHA;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;

    ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/bundle-alpha.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/certs/private.key;
    ...
}
```

I confirm that I installed the right Cert and Private Keys.

Bear in mind that I run the `AlphaSSL` Wildcard certificate.

**I suspect that I'm missing something in regards to the configuration as in my other hosting I installed the same .crt file and .key.**

Comment: What is the URL to the server? `openssl s_client` connects fine when using `GeoTrust Global CA` as `CAfile`. `website.com` is owned by a real organization. Are you sending us on a wild goose chase by providing bad information?

Comment: Hi Jww. I'm sending bogus website information. The website is owned by me, it already runs the certificate just fine, however in process of migrating to Nginx I'm facing this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue before, had todo with the order of the certs that reside inside your ssl_certificate file.
You need to include all intermediate CA certs in this file, and have them in the right order.
All I had to do was reverse the order of the certs within that file, and my problem was solved.

Your server cert should be on top, then simply go down the CA chain.

PS. My config looks like:

```
listen 443 default ssl;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server_plus.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
ssl_session_timeout 5m;
ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

Comment: Hi Ikkuh,

My certificate chain looks to be correct.
If I inverse the order, I have a private key error when restarting Nginx.

My order is:
 - My Certificate
 - Intermediate Certificate
 - Root certificate.

However, if I go to my website and check the certificate information, there is nothing regarding the chain.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: That is weird, are you sure you are using the correct certs, didn't add any extra spaces or lines.. ect in either file?
Anything in your logs that might point you to something?

Comment: In fact it was the order of the certificates. Long time passed, but I forgot to marke as answered. Thanks.

Comment: What file did you change the order in?